# Selenium webdriver 2.53.0 with firefox 45 esr not working?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I make it work? I need Firefox 45 esr to work with selenium webdriver 2.53.0 but it is throwing an exception when instantiating FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities):

```
Unable to determine the current version of FireFox using the registry, please    make sure you have installed FireFox correctly
```

Are they not compatible? How do I make webdriver work for Firefox 45 esr?

UPDATE:
I was able to get the 64 bit firefox installer to work only when I installed into C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox. For the 32 bit installer I can't get it to work anywhere. Any reason why it behaves this way?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue, webdriver version `2.53.0` should support `firefox v45`. Is firefox installed on the defalt location in your machine?

Comment: yes it is. C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox

Comment: firefox v45 works. But the esr version doesn't work. Firefox Setup 45.0esr

Comment: Yes I think esr version wouldn't work.

Comment: any workaround? would you know if all esr versions of 45 would not work?

Comment: Tried adding the file path to the Firefox binary?

Comment: Thanks! Got it working with dc.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.BinaryCapabilityName, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe");

Comment: Why is it though that I have to set the Binary Path? I installed firefox esr like any other firefox on the default location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox

Comment: I have FF 45.3.0 ESR that works fine with Selenium 2.53.0. And, since I am on a 64-bit system, the location for firefox.exe is  "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox". Please check if you've multiple versions of Firefox installed in your system. If so, please remove the other versions and re-install the Firefox 45 ESR and give it a go.

Comment: I tried uninstalling all Firefox versions then installed 45 ESR. But it still won't work. I'm checking my regedit and looks like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/Mozilla/Mozilla Firefox - for regular firefox, it has the version set on this registry entry. i.e. CurrentVersion 45.0.1. But for ESR, there are no entries here. It is in a different folder named /Mozilla Firefox ESR which has the data 45.1.1 ESR

Comment: Could it be the registry affecting the webdriver's ability to find firefox esr version thus the need for setting the binary path specifically?

Comment: I was able to get the 64 bit firefox installer to work only when I installed into C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox. For the 32 bit installer I can't get it to work anywhere. Any reason why it behaves this way?

Comment: @kentocarl you should answer your question and mark it as the answer.  I'm not sure why it's behaving the way it is, but Installing the 64 bit firefox in the Program Files (x86) worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the 64 bit firefox installer to work only when I installed into C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox. For the 32 bit installer I can't get it to work anywhere. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

47 can't run with of FirefoxDriver, Geckodriver is used. But this should be compatible.

Comment: You're right. Have to add file path to binary to get esr version working though

Comment: Why is it though that I have to set the Binary Path? I installed firefox esr like any other firefox on the default location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox